# Current Acttivity AutoStarts before timer ends?

Tags: android, countdowntimer

I am trying to start an activity as the timer starts and start the current activity again, when timer ends after 10 seconds. But after 5 seconds, current activity starts again and o onFinish() method is being called after the timer finishes.
i'm not starting the crrent activity at any other place in the current activity or in the activity being start as the timer starts. 
please help me to understand this .Thanks

```
timer= new CountDownTimer (time, 1000) {

                    public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                        switch (activity_state){
                            case 1:
                                //this toast is being used to display time
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),String.valueOf(millisUntilFinished/1000),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                if(millisUntilFinished==time){
                                    finish();
                                    startActivity(new Intent(SettingsActivity_2.this,OneYearActivity.class));}
                                break;
                            case 2:
                                if(millisUntilFinished==time)
                                {finish();startActivity(new Intent(SettingsActivity_2.this,TwoYearActivity.class));}
                                break;
                            case 3:
                                if(millisUntilFinished==time)
                                {finish();startActivity(new Intent(SettingsActivity_2.this,ThreeYearActivity.class));}
                                break;
                            case 4:
                                if(millisUntilFinished==time)
                                {finish();startActivity(new Intent(SettingsActivity_2.this,AllYearActivity.class));}
                                break;
                        }
                    }
                    public void onFinish() {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"OnFinishCalled",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        startActivity ( new Intent ( SettingsActivity_2.this,SettingsActivity_2.class ));
                    }
                }.start();
```

> OneYearActivity.java
>   this activity is being start from the 1st case.

```
public class OneYearActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_one_year_kid);
    initializing_components();
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

}}
```

I am going from  [this main screen](https://www.dropbox.com/s/37la9ykhemlskco/main.png?dl=0) to [this password screen](https://www.dropbox.com/s/korbqnkpx0l34ex/pwsc.png?dl=0) named as **SettingActivity_2** and if the password is correct, it should go to [this activity](https://www.dropbox.com/s/ehwaa6zelbzn3se/1%20year.png?dl=0) named as **OneYearActivity** and after 10 seconds, **SettingsActivity_2** should start again. but after 5 seconds, the **SettingsActivity_2** starts.

> Starting New Activity After Adding Handler
>   My Handler Code

```
handler=new Handler();
 r=new Runnable() {
 @Override
  public void run() {
finish();
 }
 };
```

> starting new Activity from OneYearActivity for playing a video

```
        learning_songs.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent intent=new Intent(OneYearActivity.this,PlayVideo.class);
        intent.putExtra("video_Id","vkRDOcma9Qk");
            startActivityForResult(intent,1);
        }
    });
```

> TheActivity that is being started from OneYearActivity to play Youtube videos

```
public class PlayVideo extends AppCompatActivity {
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_play_video);

    YouTubePlayerView youtubePlayerView =    findViewById(R.id.youtube_player_view);
    getLifecycle().addObserver(youtubePlayerView);
VideoPlayer videoPlayer=new VideoPlayer();
    Intent intent=getIntent();

String video_Id=intent.getStringExtra("video_Id");
videoPlayer.play_Video(youtubePlayerView,video_Id);

}
```

## What I am trying to do

1. Start Settings2
2. On click start OneYearActivity  which is displayed for 10 seconds
3. If user press learning_songs it plays new activity and it should finish as the timer started in the previous activity ends

## What i get

1. Start Settings2
2. On click start OneYearActivity  which is displayed for 10 seconds
3. If user press learning_songs it plays new activity and as timer ends,it     doesn't finish **PlayingVideo** activity

Answer (score 0):

OneYearActivity.java
Add below code.

```
final Handler handler = new Handler();
final Runnable r = new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        openSettingsActivity_2WithRequestCode();
    }
};
```

And call it like this in `onCreate()`

```
handler.postDelayed(r, 10000);
```

**Update 1**

If code is repeated crete one `abstract` class `(ParentActivity)` which have common code of all activities and `extends` to `AppCompactActivity`, and create child class which `extends ParentActivity` and use in code child class activity.

**Update 2**

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
 try {
  super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

  if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
       handler.postDelayed(r, 1);
  }else{
      finish();
  }
 } catch (Exception ex) {
  Toast.makeText(Activity.this, ex.toString(),
   Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
 }
}
```

**Update 3**

What is `onActivityResult`

https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result

**Note : If you need any help then tell me as per your requirement, I will update code.**

Comment: it will add much of the code repetition in my application. i dont want to create any code repetation

Comment: which kind of code is create repetition. If activity related code is repeated then create abstract activity and as per need call the activity for simplicity code.

Comment: @Nancy, dont go with countdown, as per image you application animation and game related for kids, Countdown is heavier so go with lightweight thread, i am also developed some kind of application , but never used countDownTimer, its really heavy.

Because in future your requirement will update, then you will face so many issue. With handler you can do code as per click, as per event basically as per requirement, use has-a relationship.

Comment: if i go with this approach, and start a new activity from OneYearActivity, it doesn't end the new started activity

Comment: you can create one static variable, for flag, this flag helps you , you want to start or not

Comment: this code is finishing my activity after 10 sec but if i start a new activity from OneYearActivity, the handler code vanishes

Comment: then what is your requirement there, so i can try to give solution

Comment: My requirement is that when password is entered it should start **OneYearActivity** and a timer of **defined time let say 10 sec** should start and when a button is pressed from **OneYearActivity**, it should start a new activity which is playing some youtube video and the timer should continue. as the timer ends, it should take back to **PasswordActivity** stopping everything else.

Comment: do not finish your activity when you move from OneYearActivity, and handle onActivityResult().

Comment: you mean implement handler in onActivityResult() or what?

Comment: not need to implement, declare global variable and again call, handler.postDelayed(r, 1);, actually do code as per requirement.

Comment: sorry. i really didn't get that. where to call handler?

Comment: i mean define Handler variable globally, and call in onactivityresult. if you want apply handler, call handler related code, if you not required then finish the activity

Comment: do you mean something like **@Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        handler();
    }
**

Comment: i need to implement this in OneYearActivity . right?

Comment: what is REQUEST_CODE in here?

Comment: Yes, correct @Nancy, at the time of call activity pass the request code is one variable to identify call from which place, which you want to check in onActivityResult()

Comment: please take a look again at the question. i have updated it

Comment: @Nancy, where is onActivityResult

Answer (score 0):

Your code should looks like this:

In activity, thaat you are switching state:

```
switch (activity_state) {
        case 1:
            //this toast is being used to display time
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), String.valueOf(millisUntilFinished / 1000), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            startActivity(new Intent(SettingsActivity_2.this, OneYearActivity.class));
            finish();
            break;
        case 2:
            startActivity(new Intent(SettingsActivity_2.this, TwoYearActivity.class));
            finish();
            break;
        case 3:
            startActivity(new Intent(SettingsActivity_2.this, ThreeYearActivity.class));
            finish();
            break;
        case 4:
            startActivity(new Intent(SettingsActivity_2.this, AllYearActivity.class));
            finish();
            break;

        default:
            break;
    }
```

And each next activity, that you want to cose after 10 seconds:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    //display whatever you need

    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {

            finish();
        }
    }, 10000);
}
```

Comment: if i go with this approach, and start a new activity from OneYearActivity, it doesn't  end the new started activity

Comment: @Nancy, CountDownTimer is started immediately when you call start. So while you're entering password and OneYearActivity is started several seconds already elapsed. Try not to do anything. It will start activity again in 10 seconds.You have to post 10 seconds delay in Activity where you need it. You can move code to base class as suggested by Yogesh Rathi

Answer (score 0):

In your case do the following:

**1. Start OneYearActivity from SettingsActivity_2**

```
startActivity(new Intent(this, OneYearActivity.class));
```

**2. Start PlayVideoActivity for result from OneYearActivity**

```
private static final int PLAY_VIDEO_REQUEST_CODE = 1;

/*protected */ Runnable finishAction = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            finishActivity(PLAY_VIDEO_REQUEST_CODE);
            finish();
        }
    };

/* in initialize method*/
    learning_songs.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent intent=new Intent(OneYearActivity.this,PlayVideo.class);
            intent.putExtra("video_Id","vkRDOcma9Qk");
            startActivityForResult(intent, PLAY_VIDEO_REQUEST_CODE);
            toolbar.postDelayed(finishAction, 10000);
        }
    });
```

---

**OR**

You can start from PlayVideo activity

```
youtubePlayerView.postDelayed(finishAction, 10000);
```

put Result

```
/*protected */ Runnable finishAction = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            setResult(RESULT_OK);
            finish();
        }
    };
```

And finish OneYearActivity in onActivityResult when you receive this code

```
if (resultCode == PLAY_VIDEO_REQUEST_CODE) {
    finish();
}
```

Comment: the problem is still there. when i start a new activity from **OneYearActivity**, the handler doesn't stops that activity.

Comment: please look at question again.

Comment: @Nancy. Does it work (finish) without starting new activity for result?

Comment: btw, I do not use new handler

Comment: yeah . it works with ** toolbar.postDelayed(r, 10000);** and r is **Runnable**. but still the **PlayVideo** activity doesn't close

Comment: @Nancy. I can't see where do you close PlayVideo. You close only OneYear in onActivityresult.

Comment: but you should also close and `setResult(RESULT_OK)` in PlayVideo

Comment: how to do that?

Comment: that is what i need to do and saying the same since i posted this question

Comment: @Nancy. Ok. Then just put to intent for how many seconds you want to play video (if it is different). Then call postDelayed in PlayVideoActivity in onCreate. in `Runnable` call `setResult(RESULT_OK)` and `finish()`. Then in OneYear in onActivityResult just call `finish()`

Comment: i dont have any toolbar in PLayVideo

Comment: @Nancy As I said you can call it on any view. `youtubePlayerView` is perfectly fine. I've updated answer